# SQL Server view for PII and Non PII end user

Tags: sql-server, data-masking, pii

I have situation where I need to create a view which will be used by end user who may have PII and NON-PII permission clearance controlled by AD groups.

Say i have dim_customer which contains four columns ID, Name, DoB, Country. When PII user runs

```
Select ID, Name, DoB, Country FROM dim_customer
```

the pii user should get

```
ID  NAME  DoB         Country
1   John  1999-10-10  US
```

If the same query is run by NON-PII user then they should get

```
ID  NAME     DoB         Country
1   PII DATA PII DATA    US
```

So basically same view object is used but data is displayed according to the pii clearance.

1. I dont want to create two views with pii and non-pii suffix.
2. I tried column level permission but that means when end user try the above
   query they get error "no select permission on Name and DoB Columns"
3. I have tried Data Masking but that shows "XXXX" and i would prefer "PII
   Data".

I am looking for a solution where the query runs successfully and show results as above.

Is this possible in SQL Server ?

thanks in advance

Comment: It is possible to GRANT or DENY access at a column level, and you should probably implement this if security is paramount. But this won't achieve the masking you want - users will have to avoid selecting columns they are not entitled to see

Comment: You mentioned you've tried Data Masking and it shows "XXXX". You can specify a custom string like "PII DATA".

Comment: @DanGuzman you should post that as an actual answer. It seems better than other answers to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Create two roles, one that allows PII data, and one that doesn't.  Put each user into one role or the other.  Than write your view

```
Select 
    ID, 
    Name, 
    CASE 
       WHEN IS_ROLEMEMBER ('pii_role') = 1 THEN DoB
       ELSE 'PII Data' 
    END as DoB, 
    Country 
FROM dim_customer
```